# Use 'variables' in HTML?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, variables

Insead of having to alter values for every item in the list as so

```
<li class="item drawing">
    <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/portfolio/skateboard_l.jpg">
    <img src="images/portfolio/skateboard.jpg" alt="skateboard"/>
    <h3>Skateboard</h3>
    </a>
</li>
```

Is it possible to have something like

```
item="Skateboard
<li class="item drawing">
    <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/portfolio/[item-lowercase][if "item"_l.jpg exists, echo"_l"].jpg">
    <img src="images/portfolio/[item-lowercase].jpg" alt="[item-lowercase]"/>
    <h3>[item]</h3>
    </a>
</li>
```

So I can just change the item variable for each item in the list rather than all the seperate entries. I assume this would be done using PHP or JS?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a **template system** (either in PHP or JS).

Comment: That's the word I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution that I can think of is to build an array (I would use PHP)... then use a while loop to build your list... put it all in a function and call it wherever you need it...

For example:

```
    <?php
        function itemList(){
            $items=array ("skateboard","rollerskates","scooter","rollerblades");             
            reset($items);          
            while (list(, $value) = each($items)) {
                echo '<li class="item drawing">';
                echo '<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/portfolio/' . $value . '_l.jpg">';
                echo '<img src="images/portfolio/' . $value . '.jpg" alt="' . $value . '"/>';   
                echo '<h3>' . $value . '</h3>';                                                   echo '</a>';
                echo '</li>';
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Then in your HTML file (where you want the list to be displayed):

```
<ul><?php itemList(); ?></ul>
```

If you put the function in a separate .php file, you have to include it in the HTML document:

```
<?php include ('/url/of/list.php'); ?>
```

Comment: AngularJS doesn't seem to work with FancyBox so I've opted to use your method. I was just about to say it wasn't working when I noticed you had used $list instead of $items. Seems to be working fine now, thanks.

Comment: ha... sorry about that... good catch! I'll update that now so it won't mess others up.

Comment: Is there a way to have multiple variables? For example name and type?

Comment: Yes... what I think you are referring to is called an associative array. You can read more about them here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18250/discussion-between-derek-bourgeois-and-supertod)

Answer (score 2):

You want to use templates I guess.

If you want to do it client side in JS:

- [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#template)
- [Mustache.js](http://mustache.github.com/)
- [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in PHP using `echo`.

For instance, if the image name was stored in `$images["myImage"]` and the alt was `$imageAlts["myImage"`

```
<img src="images/portfolio/<?php echo $images["myImage"]; ?>.jpg" alt="<?php echo $imageAlts["myImage"]; ?>"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) would help as well.  It lets you do stuff like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <label>Name:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
      <hr>
      <h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02 seems to be a perfect way to do it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) is a good template system for PHP. If you'd like to use PHP for templating over JavaScript, just start with one of the tutorials there (or look into other PHP template systems).

Answer (score 1):

A classic way to do this in PHP would be to create an array of items in PHP and then iterate over the array, creating the HTML list items with the appropriate [item-lowercase] entries.

I would consider doing the [if item exists] as part of the process that builds your data array so you don't have to do anything complicated when you build your html. Then, just loop through your array and display whatever is in $theItem.

This is, of course, a simplification.

```
foreach($itemList as $key=>$theItem){
    ?>
  <li class="item drawing">
   <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/portfolio/<?php echo $theItem ?>

<img src="images/portfolio/[item-lowercase].jpg" alt="[item-lowercase]"/>
<h3>[item]</h3>
</a>
</li>
    <?php

}
```